# Every time notifyDataSetChanged() is called, onBindViewHolder() is called

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use RecyclerView of android.

1) getItemId() is overridden.
2) setHasStableIds(true) is set.

but Every time notifyDataSetChanged() is called, onBindViewHolder() is called.

I think that if the item id is the same as the existing one, onBindViewHolder() should not be called.

Please let me know my misunderstanding or error in this code.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private int[] mData = {101, 102, 103, 104, 105};

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter() {
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("ExampleAdapter", "onBindViewHolder : " + position);
        holder.mTextView.setText("data : " + mData[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mData[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's expected. `notifyDataSetChanged` will refresh the view that's using the same dataset. Could you elaborate what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: what i'm trying to achieve is that onBindViewHolder() is called only for the changed items, without using notifyItemChanged().

Comment: i must have misunderstood something. i thought that "reusing the same viewholder for the same item" means "onBindViewHolder() is not called for the viewholder which already has the same item id as changed one". but it seems not. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: no problem, seems like you found the answer? :)

Comment: Even though the item id is the same, the contents can be different. So I think that calling onBindViewHolder() is natural and required. I could think again because you said "That's expected." Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DiffUtil]**(https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil)

It provides a way to calculate difference between the two list and calls related methods on the adapter like notifyItemInserted(), notifyItemRemoved(), notifyItemChanged(), etc. As a result, the whole list doesn’t get refreshed. Only the items that have been changed are refreshed. It also animates the item changes a little bit so it looks quite nice and it is also performance efficient.

Use of ListAdapter which can simplify the use of DiffUtil on a background thread. So you don't even need to call  notifyDataSetChanged().

ListAdapter was added in version 27.1.0 and belongs to maven artifact.

Change Your Adapter to Extend ListAdapter and Create a class extends DiffUtil.Itemcallback. here is my code for reference which is in kotlin.

```
  class AuthorsListAdapter(val clickListner: AuthorClickListner) : ListAdapter<Author, 
    AuthorsListAdapter.ViewHolder>(AuthorsDiffCallback()) {

    //Draw views
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
    //Bind the Values
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListner)
    }


    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding:AuthorsListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Author, clickListner: AuthorClickListner) {
            binding.clicklistner = clickListner
            binding.authors= item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }


        companion object {

            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val binding =
                    AuthorsListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }

        }


    }



    // For Update the differences in list
    class AuthorsDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Author>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Author, newItem: Author): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Author, newItem: Author): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    class AuthorClickListner(val clickListner: (author:Author) -> Unit)
    {
        fun onClick(author: Author)
        {
            clickListner(author)
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you still have any queries.

Comment: I didn't know about ListAdapter but I could learn it today thanks to you. It can be used with LiveData and it's very very convenient. Thank you !